# Fahrenheit to Celsius convert and printing problem

Tags: swift

Hi i was trying to create a function that printed out the statement f(variable)degrees Fahrenheit = c(variable) degrees Celsius in swift and I am having issues printing it mainly cause its a variable with numbers and im trying to put it into a string I tried some different types of decleratino but it hasnt worked. and sorry for repetitive questions

```
var f = 68.0;
var c = (f - 32.0) * 5.0 / 9.0;
var conversion = "f degrees Fahrenheit = c degrees Celsius"

print(conversion)
```

Comment: Use this one

var conversion = "\(f) degrees Fahrenheit = \(c) degrees Celsius"

Comment: Please choose a sensible title describing your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use String interpolation, otherwise it's just text.

Replace `c` with `\(c)` to actually get the value of variable `c` value.
Also `f` with `\(f)` for the same reason.

`var conversion = "\(f) degrees Fahrenheit = \(c) degrees Celsius"`

Comment: Probably need to String interpolate `f` too.

Comment: Thank you ill mark as answer when it lets me in 11 minutes

Comment: f is the actual value as it's not inside a string.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `conversion` is a String.

Comment: aaa, right, f on c variable is on value and on conversion variable is text.